# Regularexpressionvalidator doesn't work on asp.net updatepanels

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working on asp.net web forms. In an ascx page I have an `UpdatePanel`. Within the `UpdatePanel1`, I have an `ModalPopupExtender` from the Ajax Control Toolkit which displays a textbox for email input, which I want to validate for email input in a proper format. I have tried two approaches. In the first I used `asp:RegularExpressionValidator`. In the second, I added a javascript function on the client side click event like so:

```
OnClientClick="if(!CheckEmail()){return false};"
```

None of them works and the entry from the popup modal always get sent to the server whether the email input is correct or not. I made sure that the email input textbox has `CausesValidation="True"`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
  <asp:Panel ID="ConfirmAdd" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup"   style="display: none;" Width="530px" >  
   <div style="text-align:center">
    <b>Create New User</b>
   </div>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>User ID (Email):</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="email"  Width="300px"  runat="server"  MaxLength="50" CausesValidation="True"  ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"  Text="Email required."  ControlToValidate="email"  
                ValidationGroup="adduser"  ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="EmailRegularExpressionValidator" ControlToValidate="email" 
                ValidationExpression="\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b"
                ErrorMessage="Email must be in valid format" Text="Email must be in valid format" 
                EnableClientScript="False" runat="server" ValidationGroup="adduser" SetFocusOnError="True" />
        </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <br />
    <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click"    UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Add"  ValidationGroup="adduser"  OnClientClick="if (!CheckEmail()){return false;}" />&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="RefCancel"  runat="server" Text="Cancel" ValidationGroup="none"  />
    </div>
```

```
  </ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Why use Ajax controls when you can achieve all that with jQuery much easier and it works on all the browsers.

Comment: It is a preexisting application.

Comment: What .NET Framework version your project is targeting?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try using bootstrap modal. Create a button to open modal:**

```
    <input type="button" id="shModal" 
           name="shModal" class="btn btn-success btn-outline" 
           data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" value="New" />
```

**Then in your modal add a textbox:**

```
<div class="container row form-horizontal">

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Input Email</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="control-label col-md-4">Email</asp:Label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" CssClass="form-control text-uppercase"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdSave" CssClass="btn btn-info pull-left" Text="Save" 
                            OnClick="cmdSave_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateEmail();" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
</div><!--Item Modal-->
```

**Then add your jquery validation code:**

```
function ValidateEmail(){
        if(!isEmailValid()){
            return false;
}else{
alert('boyyyya, email is valid!');
}
        }
```